# What's the easiest way to create a console window for a windows phone 8 application project?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a windows phone 8 application and wish to create a console window for debug output purpose.

I found [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/b7a14400-6d72-4fbf-9927-0966f69ef4a2/) which basically use DllImport to get AllocConsole() from kernel32.dll.

Is there an easier way? Say, is there any c# function already provided so I don't have to DllImport?

How about the debug output window in Visual Studio. Never used it. Am I supposed to use it instead of creating a console?

Comment: Update: tried to use the DllImport approach but got a NotSupportedException: "DllImport cannot be used on user-defined methods."    Here is what I added to my project:           
[DllImport("kernel32.dll",
                    EntryPoint = "AllocConsole",
                    SetLastError = true,
                    CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
                    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern int AllocConsole();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't access the Console from Windows Phone. You can write to the debug window using `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()`. Of course this only works if you've got the debugger attached...